# Get extras from notifcation - FCM

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get extra from bundle when I open the app when click on notification.

I have this method on MainActivity:

```
    private void getBundleFromFirebaseMessaging(){
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        boolean cameFromNotification = b.getBoolean("fromNotification");
        if (cameFromNotification) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "FROM PUSH", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

The only bundle I get is the _fbSourceApplicationHasBeenSet.

This is my method on my FirebaseMessaging class

```
    private fun sendNotification(message: RemoteMessage) {
    val messageBody = message.notification?.body
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    intent.putExtra("fromNotification", true)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

    val channelId = getString(R.string.notification_channel)
    val channelName = getString(R.string.notification_channel_name)

    val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat
            .Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.login_logo)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)
            as NotificationManager

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId,
                channelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

Comment: Experiencing the same thing. Did you solve that issue? What was the problem?

Comment: After a little investigation I found out that my issue had nothing todo with the **_fbSourceApplicationHasBeenSet**

In my case I just read the intent from the wrong activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used earlier when I had faced the similar issue.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Message", message);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),notificationIndex,intent ,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), notificationTitle, notificationMessage, pendingNotificationIntent);
```

In your MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    onNewIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        if(extras.containsKey("Message"))
        {
            // get extras Notification
            String msg = extras.getString("Message");
            //next you can continue using the msg wherever the MainActivity wants
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SplashActivity in your app then it is the one to get the data from

inside onCreate()

```
if (getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        Set<String> keys = getIntent().getExtras().keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            try {
                json.put(key, JSONObject.wrap(extras.get(key)));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
        }
   }
}
```